# htmx.ajax only called twice when making multiple queries

Tags: javascript, ajax, htmx

I am using Alpinejs' `$watch()` on a given property inside multiple x-data blocks to call `htmx.ajax` with a custom handler whenever that property changes. Here is a snippet:

HTML:

```html
<div x-data="{profiles:[]}">
  <div x-data="..." x-init="$watch('profiles', val=>onProfilesChanged())">...</div>

  <div x-data="..." x-init="$watch('profiles', val=>onProfilesChanged())">...</div>

  <div x-data="..." x-init="$watch('profiles', val=>onProfilesChanged())">...</div>

  <div>
  <!-- profiles modified here in response to user input -->
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
function onProfilesChanged() {
  htmx.ajax('GET', ..., {'handler': (evt,response)=>{...}});
}
```

Debugging in the browser I can see `onProfilesChanged` being called as expected (3 times), but only 2 network requests are sent and the callback handler is then only executed twice .
The requests seem to correspond to the first and last call, and everything in-between is somehow lost (tried with more `$watch()` callbacks). The behavior is the same on both Firefox and Chromium so I doubt it is a browser limitation, but I couldn't find anything in the htmx documentation concerning the maximum number of Ajax requests that can be queued.

I am at a total loss here, any insight into what might be going on would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: the problem also happens when using `htmx.ajax()` inside a for loop, so this really does seem to be on the htmx side. There is an `hx-sync` tag to set the queue behavior for hx-get/post.. tags, but doesn't seem to work with the JS API.

Comment: Please share a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Added some example code to show the problem

Answer (score 3):

Finally managed to find a workaround: adding a dynamic `source` element to the Ajax request's options attributes fixes the issue. I am still having a limit of 2 requests per element in the case of for loops, but requests from different sources have different queues now.

Keeping this for future reference in case it helps someone else.